# How do I install the Zenvoid desktop on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

I am trying to create a touch friendly mobile device. To achieve this, I need a touch-friendly desktop environment. Based on my findings, it appears that the Zenvoid desktop would be the best option, yet I can't figure out how to install it. I have tried using the command line to install it, but I don't know how to add the repository, nor do I know the name of the software package that I need to install. I have found a Debian iso with Zenvoid installed on it, but I don't want to use it because I want Raspbian specifically. Is there a way to install Zenvoid alongside lxde? If there isn't, then please suggest another touch-friendly desktop that is capable of running on the raspberry pi 2. At the moment I am using xfce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see on zenvoid.org, this setup was built in 2012 and never developed further. It runs on smartQ devices, and sources are available if you are willing to do (a lot of!) configging and trial&error to get it to run. Doesn't sound very promising to me, especially since even if you get it to run, the experience will not be perfect as expressed by the author himself.

You might want to take a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices - there is a Touch version of Ubuntu and you might get it compiled on the rPi2, especially since it is already possible to run "plain" Ubuntu on the rPi2. Still, it doesn't seem to be a case of "take this ISO and go" but rather a customized compilation and installation.